# How to let TensorFlow XLA know the CUDA path

Tags: tensorflow

I installed TensorFlow nightly build version via the command 
`pip install tf-nightly-gpu --prefix=/tf/install/path`

When I tried to run any XLA example, TensorFlow has error "Unable to find libdevice dir. Using '.' Failed to compile ptx to cubin.  Will attempt to let GPU driver compile the ptx. Not found: /usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin/ptxas not found".

So apparently TensorFlow cannot find my CUDA path. In my system, the CUDA is installed in /cm/shared/apps/cuda/toolkit/10.0.130. Since I didn't build TensorFlow from source, by default XLA searches the folder /user/local/cuda-*. But since I do not have this folder, it will issue an error.

Currently my workaround is to create a symbolic link. I checked the TensorFlow source code in tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc. There is a comment in the file "// CUDA location explicitly specified by user via --xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir has highest priority." So how to pass values to this flag? I tried the following two environment variables, but neither of them works:

```
export XLA_FLAGS="--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/cm/shared/apps/cuda10.0/toolkit/10.0.130/"
export TF_XLA_FLAGS="--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/cm/shared/apps/cuda10.0/toolkit/10.0.130/"
```

So how to use the flag "--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir"? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

you can run `export XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/path/to/cuda` in terminal

Comment: You're a life saver. I spent 10 hours looking for a solution.

Comment: In python code, with Linux OS, one can use: os.environ['XLA_FLAGS'] = '--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/usr/lib/cuda/'

Comment: what is `/path/to/cuda` supposed to be?

Comment: If you are running Linux/Unix you can add this to your `~/.profile` file for it to happen automatically.

Comment: `/path/to/cuda` is the directory that contains `nvvm/libdevice/libdevice.10.bc`. In case of conda environments you can use `export XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=$CONDA_PREFIX`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
tensorflow                2.11.0          gpu_py310hf8ff8df_0  
ii  nvidia-dkms-525                 525.105.17-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-525               525.105.17-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
nvidia-cuda-toolkit not installed
```

nVidia T4 @GCE Ubu 22.04LTS min

```
conda install -c nvidia cuda-nvcc

ln -s /path/to/conda-env/lib/libdevice.10.bc .
```

I couldn't get the XLA_FLAGS to work

```
2023-04-21 09:17:00.947644: F tensorflow/compiler/xla/parse_flags_from_env.cc:226] Unknown flags in XLA_FLAGS: -–xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/home/rac/fulltf2/fullcuda.env/lib 
 Perhaps you meant to specify these on the TF_XLA_FLAGS envvar?
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: In the error message the dashes appear to be different `-–`. Maybe this is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

There is a code change for this issue, but not clear how to use.  Check here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23783