# i got an error about error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice in tensorflow object_detection api

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, tensorflow2.0

Windows Version: Windows 10 Pro 21H2 19044.1706
GPU: rtx2070

```
import tensorflow as tf
import torch
print(torch.__version__) #1.10.1+cu113
print(torch.version.cuda) #11.3
print(tf.__version__) #2.9.1
```

and i run

```
python .\object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py
```

i can get 'Ran 24 tests in 18.279s OK (skipped=1)' result;

But when I want to train my model, i use

```
feature_extractor {
   type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_keras'
}
```

in my pipeline_config, and i run

```
python .\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=LOCATION_OF_MY_PIPECONFIG --model_dir=LOCATION_OF_MY_MODEL_DIR
```

And then i get the following error
[image]
In my system environment variable , 'CUDA_DIR' is variable and can be accessed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem and just fixed it. The library can't find the folder even if you set the "CUDA_DIR" because it's not using that variable or any other I tried. This [post](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/libdevice-not-found-why-is-it-not-found-in-the-searched-path/3419/10) is helpful in understanding the issue. The only solution I was able to find is just copying the required files.

**Steps for a quick fix:**

1. Find where your CUDA nvvm is installed (for me it is "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6").
2. Find the working directory for your script (the environment or the directory you are running the script in).
3. Copy the entire nvvm folder into the working directory and your script should work.

This is not a great solution but until someone else posts a answer you can at least run your code.

Comment: I also get this error, but I don't really understand your solution. To where exactly did you copy your nvmm folder? How could that solve anything since the error still specifies that it is trying to read:
"${CUDA_DIR}/nvmm/libdevice"
so without knowing the value of "CUDA_DIR" I have no way of knowing where to put the nvmm folder.

Comment: Never mind, I solved it by also setting the CUDA as an XLA flag. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189268/how-to-let-tensorflow-xla-know-the-cuda-path

Comment: @MartinSonesson that solution doesn't apply to a windows enviroment, just a clarification to any other reader.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solve the same problem:

1. Go to your CUDA main folder path and its v10.x or v11.x sub-folder.

   In my case is from the directory path:
   **C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7**

   [image]
2. Copy the **nvmm** whole folder.
3. Paste it into your current python working directory.

   In my case using Pycharm, it must be the same directory with ***.idea*** and ***__pycache__*** folder, and ***venv*** folder (not shown in the photo)
   [image]
4. Run your program/code again. It should work now and won't show up ***error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice* anymore.**

Answer (score 0):

Copy the CUDA nvvm in the directory where your virtual environment exists.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

If you followed the official `tensorflow` [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) and installed `tensorflow` using `anaconda/miniconda` + `pip`, here is the location of `CUDA_DIR`:

```
/root/miniconda3/{YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
```

If you properly installed `CUDA`, this folder should contain the subfolder `nvvm` which is exactly what `tensorflow` looks for in order to find the `libdevice`.

Edit:

### Solution 2

After some experimentation, it turns out that *sometimes* even setting the `CUDA_DIR` path does not work. It turns out that `tensorflow` will look for CUDA inside the current working directory.

Solution:

1. Determine your current working directory (just execute `pwd`)
2. Copy the `libdevice.10.bc` file into your current working directory. If you used conda as mentioned above, you should find the file in this directory: `/{path_to_your_conda_environment}/nvvm/libdevice/libdevice.10.bc`

Obviously it's a terrible solution, but hey, after 5 hours I don't care anymore.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using `tensorflow 2.14.0` from within a Docker install. An upgrade did the trick for me:

`pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow==2.15.0 keras==2.15.0`

Hope this helps!